# Operator>> Overloading with C++ maps

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, overloading, operator-keyword

I made a class student

```
    class student
{
      private:
              string ID;
              string name;
              int age;
      public:
             ....
};
```

I want to get values from user and put it in a map so I created an Operator>> Overloading

```
istream& operator>> (istream& in, student person){
    string newID;
    string newname;
    int newage;
    return in;
}
```

and so when it goes to the cin part

```
    student person;
    cin>>person;
```

when it adds person to the data map it calls for values from the default constructor and not the cin

What to do?

Comment: You might want to use a reference.

Comment: `person = student(newID, newname, newage);` This is destroyed when the  function ends. Pass person by reference.

Comment: I did try that but it gives me an error saying "ambiguous overload for 'operator>>' in 'std::cin >> person'"

Comment: By the way, once you have your reference sorted out, you can simplify your `operator>>`: `{ return in >> person.ID >> person.name >> person.wage; }`

Comment: In the future, don't remove code from your questions – it was critical in answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator needs to take the second argument by reference:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, student& person) {
                                        ^ HERE
```

Otherwise the changes you make to `person` never make it out of `operator>>()`.

Comment: I did try that but it gives me an error saying "ambiguous overload for 'operator>>' in 'std::cin >> person'"

Comment: @MarkKanemura: What overloads do you have? Did the compiler say what the candidates were?

Comment: candidates are: std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, student)
     std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, student&)

Comment: @MarkKanemura: Get rid of the first one and only keep the second.

Comment: I suspect that you have a `friend` declaration for `operator>>` and then later a definition of it. You must change both the definition and declaration of `operator>>`.

Comment: Oh it worked .. turns out I changed it in the function but forgot to change it in the function decleration .. Thanks a lot :)